# Changing password for Samba on RPi4

Tags: samba

i succesfully installed and started samba with password as user1. Lets call it password1.
But i have more raspberries running and i chose to put all passwords same to all of them, so i changed this user1 password to password2.

Samba password login remained with password1.

When i change it with
smbpasswd -a user1 OR
smbpasswd -x and then smbpasswd -a user1 OR
smbpasswd -a user2

i cannot login anymore to samba, i can only use samba with user and password1.
I tried uninstalling and installing samba again, with no success, i can only login with password1.

Suggestions how to change it?

Comment: Clarification: Your scenario is not entirely clear to me. Are you running `samba` on several RPis? Please explain this.

Comment: `i cannot login anymore to samba, i can only use samba with user and password1` ... so you can login, you just can't change the password

Comment: Jaromanda: Yes, i can login to system, i mean when i connect through windows to samba share, raspberry will not accept password2 <br> Seamus: Yes, i am using it so i can write python programs remotely, and share files between work PC and raspberries.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is still not clear... maybe try a "block diagram" showing your Samba servers, your Samba clients, what you **can** do & what you **can't** do? This is generally not a difficult problem to solve, but your scenario remains unclear to me.

Comment: @Seamus - my servers are not importans. I have only one which had User X and user password A with samba also having User X password A, <br> but i need to change it to samba  UserX and password B. B is also current UserX password. You need a block diagram, come on.